# R: Fitting a model with periodic, nonlinear and categorical components

Tags: r, regression, time-series, nonlinear-regression, seasonality

Can anyone give me some advice on how to fit a model with linear (some categorical), non-linear and time series components in R? I don't want to use a non-parametric model like a Loess smooth or similar, as I want a simple and well defined confidence interval and the ability to extrapolate. I also don't have sufficient data to justify a non-parametric model. The model form should be as below, note that there are time series components that exhibit seasonal behavior (and my notation probably doesn't express this well!):

$$\hat{Y} = \beta_0 +\beta_1 X_1 + e^{\beta_2X_{1}}+\beta_3 f_{harmonic}(X_t) + \epsilon_i 
$$ 
Where $\epsilon_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma) $.

I know that the `nls` package can fit non-linear models, and I could use that to fit a harmonic function to get the time series part of the model. But I understand that it doesn't work for factor type variables, so I'm reluctant to use it.

Equally, I understand that the `dynlm` package can be used to fit dynamic linear models (and could therefore account for seasonality), but it cannot fit dynamic models of the form specified above to the best of my knowledge.

Would the preferred approach be to simply perform each model sequentially on the residuals of the previous procedure? If I did this, how would I ultimately combine them together to create predictions on new data?

Comment: As a side note, I'm getting very strange behaviour even trying to fit an exponential and linear term to the model!

Comment: Have you considered using Kalman filtering?

Comment: Kalman filtering really isn't something I'm very familiar with at all! Do you have any resources which might help me understand how it could be applied in this case? Would it be to update the regression parameters dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not attempting to give a complete answer, but I note that you don't mention the **nlme** package, which provides for both nonlinear models and time-series structures on the errors. It is associated with a book by Pinheiro and Bates (2000), *Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-PLUS* (Springer), which includes a lot of examples.

Comment: Are you able to let me know how I might use this package to deseasonalise the data? I haven't been able to get hold of that book, however from the package documentation it looks as though it might suit my purposes.

Comment: Been a while since I've actually used it. Offhand, there is some promise in the `corARMA` structure, though, as you could specify `p=12` to get a seasonal autocorrelation. But then I think you might be estimating all orders 1-11 too.The book *really* helps. At UI it's available as an e-book through a special deal our library has with Springer. If you have access to a univ.ibrary, maybe you have the same.

Comment: I'm going to award you the bounty, because I think you've come very close to answering the question with this, it looks as though that CorARMA function may solve quite a few of my problems here.

Comment: Thanks! I will add to the discussion of Sid's answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect this model to have rather funky behavior. The setup to be rather ill conditioned. To see why, notice that even small changes in $\beta_{2}$ will cause rather huge changes in the output. My suggestion is to simplify the model. Call $exp(\beta_{3}) = \beta_{4}, exp(X_{1})= X_{2}$ and $f_{Harmnoic}(X) = X_{3}$. Now we have a linear regression
which is straight forward to solve then interpret the results using whatever method you feel worthwhile to proceed with.

Comment: I was close to giving you the bounty for this one, as it answers a few of my questions. I have been having huge trouble getting this model to converge, however the main thrust of my question was around getting linear, non-linear and time series components all into the same model, so I've given it to Russ this time. When  I come back to ask a question about fitting exponential models (it'll be any day now!) I hope you'll be able to give me some more in depth advise on this.

Comment: However, by way of direct feedback to this I believe that the equation you're suggesting would yield the equivalent of $e^{\beta}e^X = e^{\beta_1+X_1}$ rather than $e^{\beta_1X_1}$? This would prevent the coefficient from controlling the curvature of the exponential function, which is what it needs.

Comment: Having explored more thoroughly, I think I actually need something like an inverse logistic function such as $C-\frac{C} {e^{\beta_1+\beta_2X}}$ But fitting this is a nightmare. Any advice would be much appreciated if you can help.

Comment: First off, apologies for not noticing the silly mistake. I am not a huge fan of fitting these exceedingly complicated functions. Think of what happens to the variance in your answer if you are off by a bit. I would still prefer a simple model where you set $X_{4} = X_{2}^{\beta}$ and then estimate $\beta$ in a subsequent step.

Comment: What are the orders of your X values and Y values. Do you think you could argue $\beta_{2} X_{1}$ will be close to 0 after you normalize Y (my ration behind this is that if Y is between -1 and 1 and for some X value I want the exponential to not grow too fast it has to be rather tame). In that case you could put in $exp(\beta_{2}X) \approx (1 + \beta_{2}X)$ and fit that model...wishful thinking but no harm in tossing it out there :)

Comment: I didn't realize before the form of the model was in question. The inverse logistic may not be a nightmare at all, because there are a variety of self-starting models available: in R, do `?selfStart`, which links to the individual help pages, including `SSlogis` for logistic curves. It took me a while to find these, as I looked for them in the nlme package, where they used to be, but now apparently have been moved to the main **stats** package. The Pinheiro-Bates book (still hoping you can find this) shows graphs of all these self-starting models and is really useful for guidance in choosing.

Comment: I've discovered that using the NLS function and reducing the step size and increasing the iterations tends to yield good results. I believe initially my main issue was with the step size being too large - some of the coefficients are of the order of $10^{-5}$! Once I get ahold of the Pinheiro-Bates book, I should be able to add in these time series components hopefully and that should complete the model!